# Fragment field is sometimes null even though rotation is disabled

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I am passing data to a fragment instance variable, and then on submit, that data is being referenced. For some reason, that field is sometimes being nulled on submit . Do I have to retain that field somehow even though the app doesn't rotate ?

Data being passed to fragment

```
                Fragment fragment = Fragment.newInstance();
                fragment.data= data;
```

Fragment transaction being created

```
            fragmentTransaction.hide(this);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStackClass);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Data handle on submit listener

```
            private data data;                

            private OnSingleClickListener submitListener = new 
            OnSingleClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSingleClick(View v) {


        String id = data.getQuestionId;  // error occured on this line because data was 
                           // null

        });
```

Error stalk trace

```
            Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to 
            invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String 
            com.expa.Data.getQuestionId()' on a null object reference
            at com.expa.fragments.Fragment$1.onSingleClick(Unknown Source)
            at com.expa.Listener.OnSingleClickListener.onClick(Unknown 
            Source)
```

Comment: 1. Rename your `Fragment` class to anything but
2. Pass `data` as parameter of `newInstance()`
This probably will not solve your problem, but you will have a chance of debugging.

Comment: @Gotaiasits Thanks, but this isn't the actual name of the fragment class, I changed it to hide which client I am working for. Also the stack error is pretty clear about which object is null.

Comment: Yes, object might be apparent, but instance isn't. Output to logcat `Fragment` instance after creation, It probably will not be the same as the one(s) that throws exception.
Its either "wrong" `Fragment` or "wrong" `data` intance